# Janela Modal no evento click

Tags: jquery

Ola galera estou com um problema, tenho que fazer um botão ter "2 funções" na verdade esta tudo funcionando corretamente, so que meu cliente quer o seguinte...

quando o usuário clicar em cadastrar e estiver todos campos correto, ele cadastra e mostra a mensagem de sucesso em uma modal, com um botão que redireciona para home. E se ele deixar de preencher algum campo e clicar no botão ele mostra uma mensagem na label mesmo.

esta tudo certo funcionando só não sei como fazer, pois no que eu tentei, ele mostra a modal sempre que clicar no botão preenchendo ou não os campos.

Aqui é minha modal;
   
          /* java janela modal serviços */
          var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

```
      $j(document).ready(function () {
          var nome = $("#txtNome").val();
          var mail = $("#txtEmailC").val();
          var fone = $("#txtFoneC").val();

          if (nome != "" && mail != "" && fone != "") {
            //$(document).ready(function () {

                $("a[rel=modal]").click(function (ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();

                    var id = $(this).attr("href");

                    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
                    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

                    //colocando cor de fundo
                    $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });
                    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
                    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

                    var winH = $(window).height();
                    var winW = $(window).width();

                    $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
                    $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);
                    $(id).fadeIn(2000);
                });

                $('.window2 .close').click(function (ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    $('#mask').hide();
                    $('.window2').hide();
                });

                $('#mask').click(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $('.window2').hide();
                });
            //});
        }

      });
   </script>
```

aqui o botao que chama a modal caso esteja tudo preenchido certinho:

Bem esta assim se alguem souber outra solução ou se der pra resolver esta mesmo.
  Alguém sabe como devo fazer?

Comment: Pelo que pude entender, tudo indica que está faltando utilizar um condicional **if else** para verificar se os campos estão ou não vazios, e executar as ações correspondentes.

Comment: Sem olhar o código fica difícil informar qual o problema

Comment: @Delivery-TI Poste o código para analisar.

Comment: uso if else mas ele ai mostro a mensagem em label. tem como passar a modal dentro de if ...else?

Comment: Tem como direcionar a modal dentro de uma estrutura if...else ? pois a modal ja esta pronta mas nao sei como fazer para ela aparecer apenas se o cadastro for realizado deixei a mensagem na label mesmo, mas não gosto muito acho pouco profissional. kkkk

Comment: Respondí à sua pergunta. Como pôde ler, a sua pergunta está incompleta. Por favor seja mais completo quando fizer perguntas e dê uma olhada na central de ajuda: __http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve__

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que você não colocou nenhum código na sua pergunta, não é possível dar uma resposta ajustada ao seu código que lhe seria bem mais util. Assim respondo mais em teoria e espero que isso o ajude.

Os passos que deve seguir são:

1 - **Criar um selector para todos os campos.** Por exemplo:

```
var campos = $('input, texarea');
```

2- **Percorrer um a um e verificar se estão preenchidos.** Aqui tenho de adivinhar, pois falta informação na sua pergunta.
O código em baixo filtra os elementos e deixa uma array (lista) só com os elementos que não estão preenchidos:

```
campos = campos.filter(function(){ return this.value != ''; });
```

3 - **verificar e tomar acção no caso de haver (ou não) campos por preencher**, criando uma regra `if`. Ou seja, no caso `x`fazer uma coisa, no caso `y` fazer outra coisa. Aqui tenho de imaginar também parte do seu código e vou assumir que todos os inputs têm nome. Se não fôr esse o caso tem de ser mais específico na resposta.

```
if (campos.length){ // caso x, "todos os campos estão preenchidos"
    modal.open();
}else{ // caso y, "há campos por preencher"
    alert('Tem campos por preencher! Porfavor verifique os campos ' + campos.map(function(){ return this.name; }).join(' ,'));
}
```